# Looking for travel quotes

Tags: recommendations

**I'm looking for inspiring travel quotes.**
I'm not entirely sure it is an appropriate travel question according to the FAQ, but when you ask non-travelers for travel quotes, usually the term 'travel' is interpeted in such a broad way, that the list becomes cluttered with (in my opinion) non-related quotes. Therefore I decided to ask the question anyway.

I've included a list of common travel quotes I've already collected:

```
A journey of a thousand miles begins with a single step.
~ Confucius

I haven't been everywhere, but it's on my list.
~ Susan Sontag

I travel a lot; I hate having my life disrupted by routine.
~ Caskie Stinnett

I travel not to go anywhere, but to go. I travel for travel's sake. The great affair is to
move.
~ Robert Louis Stevenson

It is better to travel one mile than to read a thousand books.
~ Confucius

It is not down in any map; true places never are.
~ Herman Melville

Like all great travellers, I have seen more than I remember, and remember more than I have
seen.
~ Benjamin Disraeli

Some parts of the world you make a conscious effort to visit and others have to wait until
fate delivers you there.
~ Tony Hawks

The World is a book, and those who do not travel read only a page.
~ St. Augustine
```

Comment: +1 but as it stands I agree with you that in its current form it isn't an appropriate question. I would rephrase the question to be more specific. Something like "is there a wiki capturing travel related quotes?"

Comment: I'm not surprised by the votes to close, I am however surprised by all teh downvotes.

Comment: I would appriciate it the downvoters would, in accordance with the etiquette, at least leave a comment.

Comment: If travel.SE has an equiavlent "cousin site" like programmers.SE is for stackoverflow, I would think this might be on-topic there, but we have no such site so the chat room is probably the best place for now ....

Answer (score 4):

Did you already consult travel quotes on [Wikiquote](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Travel)

Comment: I didn't know the list, and while intersting, I'm also surprised: only 1 of the (well known) quotes listed in my question is mentioned there.

Comment: The success behind any wiki is that you add your missing quotes ;)

Comment: I long ago stopped editing on wikipedia and related websites.